# React Boostrap custom header for Panel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, panel

```
<Panel header={<CustomComponent title="someTitle">someText</CustomComponent>} />
```

Only `someText` is clickable (which expands/contracts the Panel), but not any other component `CustomComponent` renders (eg. `someTitle`).

Is there a way to make the entire panel header clickable?

Comment: what do you mean by clickable? you need an action to be dispatched on click
?

Comment: @Jeffin The clickable area to expand/collapse the Panel (automatically, without additional onClick prop)